# Adding "Contact Us" action does not work properly in my iOS App

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS development and I'm facing a problem with creating a "Contact Us" Button.
I've followed some tutorials on how to include sending email action to my app, I've done everything correctly and added everything to my app but it just won't work giving me the following message in XCode :

```
2017-08-16 21:59:51.919774+0300 KurdishGuardSecurity[460:64579] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-08-16 21:59:51.921951+0300 KurdishGuardSecurity[460:64579] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2017-08-16 21:59:52.180335+0300 KurdishGuardSecurity[460:64653] 0x170155b30 Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x170155b30> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Result" => <int64: 0x170227860>: 29
}
2017-08-16 21:59:52.181586+0300 KurdishGuardSecurity[460:64653] 0x170156e70 Daemon configuration query reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x170156e70> { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Dictionary" => <dictionary: 0x1701564d0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "ServerURL" => <dictionary: 0x170155f50> { count = 3, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
        "com.apple.CFURL.magic" => <uuid: 0x17025c740> C3853DCC-9776-4114-B6C1-FD9F51944A6D
        "com.apple.CFURL.string" => <string: 0x170252060> { length = 30, contents = "https://mesu.apple.com/assets/" }
        "com.apple.CFURL.base" => <null: 0x1a3276e80>: null-object
    }
}
"Result" => <int64: 0x1702248e0>: 0
}
2017-08-16 21:59:52.181819+0300 KurdishGuardSecurity[460:64653] [MobileAssetError:29] Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker
2017-08-16 22:10:40.384670+0300 KurdishGuardSecurity[460:66842] [MC] Invalidating cache
2017-08-16 22:10:40.389685+0300 KurdishGuardSecurity[460:66843] [MC] Invalidating cache
2017-08-16 22:10:40.400291+0300 KurdishGuardSecurity[460:64579] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

This problem persists even though I have no Text Field or anything throughout the app I have read a few topics on this issue and they all had Text Fields and they solved the problem by disabling Spell Check feature, I've also tried starting a whole new app only to test if my code works correctly to send emails and it does I have another app that only has a single button that does the "Contact Us" action code and it works perfectly but it just doesn't work with my current app, any suggestions?

Here is my ViewController.swift code that I use :

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func contactMe(_ sender: Any) {
    self.sendEmail()

    }
}
extension ViewController:MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate{

func sendEmail(){
    let mailVC = configureMainComposeViewController()

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
        self.present(mailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}

private func configureMainComposeViewController()->MFMailComposeViewController{
    let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailVC.setToRecipients(["info@kurdishguard.com"])

    return mailVC
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    print("Sent Mail",result)
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I've been working on this app for months now and I don't want to start over because of a single button's action.

Comment: @matt sorry that happened during copy pasting to the post the code compiles correctly and I will edit this now, and yes I try it on 2 devices an iPhone 5 on iOS 8 and an iPhone 7 on iOS 10.3.3 and when I click the button only the Keyboard appears on the screen and I see the posted message in xcode, same thing happens in Simulator for some reason but a different message is shown there but that one is because Simulator does not support the mailing app.

Comment: So here's an idea. Make a new project directly form the single view app template. Paste your code into it. Put a button in the storyboard and hook it to your `contactMe` action. Build, run, tap the button. Does it work now?

Comment: My guess is that you're going this somewhere you haven't told us about — somewhere illegal. It all depends on where this view controller is. For example, you might be trying to do it an extension of some kind; _that's_ certainly never going to work. But you have not told us what you're really doing, so I can't know for sure.

Comment: @matt I just did what you said, created a single view application placed a button there and directly copy pasted everything I did there and it worked perfectly ..I don't really understand what you mean by "somewhere illegal" as I mentioned I'm new to iOS Programming and this is my first app, I started this app back in 2016 and I just started working on it again just about a week ago so can it be compatibility issue since I updated XCode and now I'm using iOS 10?

Comment: Well, as I said, there must be some crucial difference between the project you just made and your real app. But I have no way of knowing what it is; you are the only one who can see it.